# How to track the sequences in the file changes with Inotifywait

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, inotifywait

Currently I am monitoring the files by using above code, it works as expected. Basically I am monitoring the opened text files and executing commands.

```
inotifywait -m -q /home/testDir -e open |
    while read path action file; do

        if [[ "$file" =~ .*txt$ ]]; then
      #  execute command
        fi
    done
```

I wonder, how can I monitor the sequences of the inotifywait events and execute command.

For example, how can I execute a command or echo something when there is a **open,access,close_nowrite** event in the directory?

```
/home/TestDir OPEN test.txt
/home/TestDir ACCESS test.txt
/home/TestDIr CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE test.txt
```

Comment: Events are reported as they happen, but there is no logic in inotify to detect a sequence of events.  You could write something to read the output and do that detection however.